# Application Role and extended procedure rights

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a custom procedure that basically replaces msdb.dbo.SP_ADDTASK which works fine when using a user with database role permissions, but when I switch to an application_role permissions scheme, the same procedure fails when trying to access xp_sqlagent_is_starting. I assume that this is the first in a long chain of extended procs that would fail if I simply explicitly granted execute, and I have not had to do this prior to testing with application role permissions.

Both the database role and the application role have the same permissions, and I cannot see any permissions on the original user account or even on the extended proc beyond the role securables, so why am I being denied execute when using the application role?

Comment: How do you expect anybody to answer this? You have a customer stored procedure that does something. But that code isn't posted. You said you get an error, but we don't know what that error is. Many people here are willing and able to help but you first have to ask a question with enough details so we can.

Comment: The custom procedure code is not pertinent to the question beyond the fact that it calls xp_sqlagent_is_starting.  The error is The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_sqlagent_is_starting.  This is not a code question so much as a question about the inherent permissions differences between a database role and user permissions, and an application_role.

Comment: Are the database role and the application role owned by the same database principal? If not, you could be running afoul of permission chaining.